# Slider text Cutting on Ipad/Iphone

Tags: html, css

I have having below mentioned as in screen shot issue on ipad. text is cutting off at the end (N and W) here is css code for:

```
.slide-caption {
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: bebasneue;
    font-size: 26.77px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 123px;
    padding: 0 36px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 191px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: its due to overflow hidden give wrapper some padding it will fix it

Comment: thanks for suggestion...i have checked thoroughly but can't caught issue u have mentioned...may bebasneu font is have some issue i guess...

Comment: if you have a online link please send i can help you

Comment: sorry i can't share it here but issue is only with 'W' & 'N' only.

Comment: you dont you give extra padding to right to check its font issue or browser issue